# LaTeX ignoring tabs in verbatim

Tags: latex, formatting

I need to write a whole bunch of pseudo code and I got annoyed using all the "\ >\=" with the \begin{tabbing} command, so I decided to use \begin{verbatim} instead. This was working fine for me until I got to a point in which I had to indent 4 times in a row. When I get to 4 tabs in a row it puts the "character" >> at the beginning of my line and then when I generate the pdf it is not indented at all. How do I get latex to stop reformatting my lines when I use verbatim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know in what code realm you are working or if this will do any better, but have you checked out the listings algorithm or program [packages](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode)? They may have better magic in them.